# RxJS partition. ERROR - is missing the following properties from type

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

there is code:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        [this.newReleaseNotes$, this.readReleaseNotes$] = partition(this.getReleaseNotes$(), ({ id }: ReleaseNoteInterface) =>
            this.releaseNotesService.readReleaseNotes.includes(id),
        );
    }

    private getReleaseNotes$(): Observable<ReleaseNoteInterface[]> {
        return forkJoin(this.releaseNotes.map((releaseNoteId: string) => this.releaseNotesService.fetchReleaseNoteById$(releaseNoteId)));
    }
```

this code throws an error in TypeScript:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '({ id }: ReleaseNoteInterface) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ReleaseNoteInterface[], index
> : number) => boolean'.
> [0]       Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
> [0]         Type 'ReleaseNoteInterface[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReleaseNoteInterface': id, type, importance, actuality, and 8 more.

method this.releaseNotesService.fetchReleaseNoteById $ makes a request to the server and returns `Observable<ReleaseNoteInterface>`

How to use the **partition** operator correctly to solve my problem?

Comment: can you clarify what you're trying to do? as this seems like you're misusing partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forkJoin` emits an array of it's inner observables, so `partition` is expecting type `ReleaseNoteInterface[]`, not type `ReleaseNoteInterface`.

so your `partition` would have to operate on that array:

```
    partition(this.getReleaseNotes$(), (releaseNotes: ReleaseNoteInterface[]) =>
        // unclear what to do with the array here?
        releaseNotes.some(({id}) => this.releaseNotesService.readReleaseNotes.includes(id))
    );
```

this would create two observable streams, one where any of the ids in the array meet the condition and one where none of the ids in the array meet the condition. It's doubtful that this is what you want.

`partition` is used to split an observable stream into 2 streams. While `forkJoin` is a higher order observable, used to combine multiple observables into one, and `forkJoin` by definition only ever emits once, and it will emit one array of all it's inner observables once all inners have completed. So using `partition` on a `forkJoin` is illogical, as `partition` exists to split a stream of multiple emissions and `forkJoin` is only a single emission observable.

what you probably want to do is this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   const sharedNotes$ = this.getReleaseNotes$(); // get the sahred

   this.newReleaseNotes$ = sharedNotes$.pipe( // map and filter the array
     map(releaseNotes => releaseNotes.filter(({id}) => this.releaseNotesService.readReleaseNotes.includes(id)))
   )

   this.readReleaseNotes$ = sharedNotes$.pipe( // map and filter the array
     map(releaseNotes => releaseNotes.filter(({id}) => !this.releaseNotesService.readReleaseNotes.includes(id)))
   )

}

private getReleaseNotes$(): Observable<ReleaseNoteInterface[]> {
    return forkJoin(this.releaseNotes.map((releaseNoteId: string) => this.releaseNotesService.fetchReleaseNoteById$(releaseNoteId))).pipe(
      share() // share it to avoid multiple calls
    );
}
```

this gives you two observables, both arrays of release notes, one with items meeting the condition, and the other with items not meeting the condition.

There are other logical ways to set this up, like only having one observable that meets the interface `{ newReleaseNotes: ReleaseNoteInterface[], readReleaseNotes: ReleaseNoteInterface[] }` and using a `map` operator to transform into that.

Comment: Added a comment in a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

@bryan60, thanks for the explanation! Did a little differently:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.newReleaseNotes$ = this.getReleaseNotes$(this.releaseNotes.filter((id: string) => !this.releaseNotesService.readReleaseNotes.includes(id)));
        this.readReleaseNotes$ = this.getReleaseNotes$(this.releaseNotes.filter((id: string) => this.releaseNotesService.readReleaseNotes.includes(id)));
    }

    private getReleaseNotes$(releaseNotesIds: string[]): Observable<ReleaseNoteInterface[]> {
        return forkJoin(releaseNotesIds.map((releaseNoteId: string) => this.releaseNotesService.fetchReleaseNoteById$(releaseNoteId)));
    }
```

Initially, I just wanted to beautifully solve this problem using the `partion` function.
Maybe there is an option to replace `forkJoin` with something else that `partion` can work with?

Comment: What you’ve done seems like a good solution. Partition isn’t the operator you want to use here.